# Unable to send email using Gmail SMTP in Powershell. Error: smtpServer requires secure connection or client was not authenticated. How to fix?

Tags: powershell, smtp

I need to check if smtp.gmail.com is working correctly with below requirements:

Requirements:

- Host : smtp.gmail.com
- SMTPSecure : tls
- SMTPAuth : true
- Username : myUser@mydomain.es
- Password : myPassword
- Port : 587

So I have done below two scripts in Powershell to check it:

**ATTEMPT #1**

```
$smtpserver= "smtp.gmail.com"
$from = "myAccount@mydomain.com"
$copy = "myAccount@mydomain.com"
$recipient = "anotherAccount@mydomain.com"
$subject = "SMTP GMAIL TEST"
$body = "SMTP GMAIL TEST"
$port = "587"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myUser@mydomain.es", $secpasswd)

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Port $port -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From $from -To $recipient -Cc $copy -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

**ATTEMPT #2**

```
$User = "myAccount@mydomain.com"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myUser@mydomain.es", $secpasswd)
$EmailTo = "anotherAccount@mydomain.com"
$EmailCopy = "myAccount@mydomain.com"
$EmailFrom = "myAccount@mydomain.com"
$Subject = "SMTP GMAIL TEST" 
$Body = "SMTP GMAIL TEST" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPMessage.CC.Add($EmailCopy)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($cred.UserName, $cred.Password); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

But I always get the error message:

> smtpServer requires secure connection or client was not authenticated.
>   the server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: I want to point out that `$cred = Get-Credential` is far more secure than embedding the password in your plaintext script. You can store it off for later use (on that system by the same user) by doing `Get-Credential | Export-CliXml \path\to\cred.xml`. You can read it back in by `$cred = Import-CliXml \path\to\cred.xml`.